# Best practise for change the IP address of web front end server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, iis

change the IP of existing sharepoint web front end server and best practise for change the iP of sharepoint server, is any issues to web applicatons and sharepont farm

Answer (score 4):

I am sure SharePoint Does not store the IP information. You have to make sure the following things:

- if using the Load balancer then Ip address should be updated
- DNS record should be update as well.
- if you are using IP address in AAM, that should also be updated.
- Also make sure in IIS( if you are binding IP address) is properly updated.

Other than that i think it is simple change.